# Decrypt Laravel Password Reset Token

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am writing a test that ensures that the password reset functionality of my application works. The password reset system was created using the `php artisan make:auth` command. In order to make the test pass I need to automate a GET request to `/password/reset/{$token}` where `$token` is the value stored in the `password_resets` table. Laravel stores the token like this:

`$2y$10$9grKb3c6.Toiv0kjUWbCUeT8Q8D.Fg2gZ/xDLGQUAkmdyHigmRkNW`

but when Laravel sends the password reset email to the user, the reset token looks like this in the email:

`382aa64567ecd05a774c2e4ebb199d3340a1424300707053354c749c10487594`.

My GET request to `/password/reset/$2y$10$9grKb3c6.Toiv0kjUWbCUeT8Q8D.Fg2gZ/xDLGQUAkmdyHigmRkNW` fails due to the forward slash in the reset token. (*Right after the 'g2gZ'*)

I tried using the helper function `decrypt()` but had no luck.

**How can I convert the password reset token I pull from the `password_resets` table to match what Laravel sends to the user?**

*Not sure if this is relevant but I did upgrade my application from 5.3 to 5.4.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get token from closure used for additional checks passed to Notification's assertSentTo method because `$token` is a public property of standard `ResetPassword` notification.

In your test:

```
Notification::fake();

$this->postJson('api/user/reset', ['email' => $user->email])
    ->assertStatus(200);

$token = '';

Notification::assertSentTo(
    $this->user,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword::class,
    function ($notification, $channels) use (&$token) {
        $token = $notification->token;

        return true;
    });

$this->postJson('api/user/resetting', [
    'email' => $user->email,
    'token' => $token,
    'password' => '87538753',
    'password_confirmation' => '87538753'
])
    ->assertStatus(200);
```

Comment: @pinguinjkeke can you please explain why you are using Notification::fake(); why we are using Notification here...?

Comment: @usama Laravel Notification Channels can be used to send Mailables too. Since some time standard password reset mail sends as Notification.
I'm using ```Notification::fake()``` for testing purposes and calling fake notifications will'not sent real one, just store info about it inside tests. Check this link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mocking#notification-fake

Comment: Cleanest solution I have seen so far. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4):

The token stored in the `password_resets` table is hashed just like a normal password, so you can't reverse it to get the original token.

I suggest that you use the [`log` mail driver](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#mail-and-local-development) when running tests. Then the password reset email will be printed in plain text in the laravel log and you can grab the token from that.

Comment: Good idea to use the log driver. combine that with an easily preg_match delimiter and it would be pretty quick and easy to grab.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help guys. I need to grab the token **before** encryption for my test. Seems like grabbing it from the log file will be the way to go.

Comment: @DenisPriebe I have the exact same problem, but I didn't really understand how you solved it. Did you implement a solution? Can you append it to y?our question? It would be quite nice! Tx!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, the hash that's saved is a bcrypted value of a sha256 hash of a random 40 digit number. which means it's not reversible just one way checkable.

Answer (score 2):

For testing the password reset functionality, I replace the generated token from the `password_reset` table with a new one.

The reset token is created with the `createTokenRepository()` method - `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBrokerManager.php`

For hashing the created token, Laravel uses the `make()` method - `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php`

```php
public function test_it_should_reset_the_password()
{

    Mail::fake();

    $user = factory(App\User::class)->create();

    $response = $this->json('POST', 'api/password/email',
                    [
                        'email' => $user->email
                    ]);
    $response->assertStatus(202);

    Mail::hasSent($user, ResetPassword::class);

    // Since we don't know the emailed token from 
    // the previous JSON call, we're
    // gonna replace the token with a new one
    $token = hash_hmac('sha256', Str::random(40), $user);
    DB::table('password_resets')
            ->where('email', $user->email)
            ->update([
                'token' => password_hash($token, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => '10'])
            ]);

    $response = $this->json('POST', 'api/password/reset', [
                    'email'                 => $user->email,
                    'password'              => 'new_user_password',
                    'password_confirmation' => 'new_user_password',
                    'token'                 => $token
                ]);
    $response->assertStatus(202);

    $response = $this->json('POST', 'api/login',
                    [
                        'email' => $user->email,
                        'password' => 'new_user_password'
                    ]);
    $response->assertStatus(202);
    // check for JWT token
    $response->assertJson(['token' => true]);

}
```